# Como utilizar, crear o manejar Emojis en Python V3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, script, email

Me encuentro trabajando en un script de automatización de correos de saludos de cumpleaños de una organización. Pero quiero darle un toque mas bonito y es con la inserción de emojis. No se manejarlos :( Alguien me podría ayudar en explicarme como se hace?

Comment: Hola @Pablo Angel Bienvenido a Stack Overflow.  Te invito a que revises las recomendaciones en [¿como elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: python tiene esta [librería para los emojis](https://pypi.org/project/emoji/), también puedes ver ahí ejemplos y su documentación

Answer (score 3):

Un emoji es un carácter más para python, igual que puedan serlo "A", "ñ", o "漢".

Como tales, pueden aparecer formando parte de una cadena sin más. Así por ejemplo el siguiente programa funcionará sin problemas:

```
print("Hola ")
```

El problema no lo tiene python, sino más bien tú a la hora de insertar ese símbolo en la cadena, ya que probablemente tu teclado no tenga Emojis. Ante este problema tienes dos vías:

1. Buscar el emoji en internet y copiarlo y pegarlo como parte de tu código.
2. Buscar código Unicode del emoji (en el caso del emoji anterior es  U+1F30E, valor que puedes encontrar por ejemplo en emojipedia) y meterlo en la cadena con el formato especial `\U0001F30E`

La ventaja del primer método es que el código fuente ya te muestra qué va a salir al imprimir. Usando el segundo método el código fuente se vería así:

```
print("Hola \U0001F30E")
```

Pero al ejecutar el programa saldría `Hola`  (siempre que la consola en la que el programa sea ejecutado tenga soporte para Unicode y tenga una fuente que incluya el carácter en cuestión).

Hay bibliotecas python que te permiten especificar los caracteres emoji con otra sintaxis, evitando que tengas que conocer su código unicode o que tengas que copiar y pegar el carácter en sí. Usando una de estas bibliotecas podrías poner algo como:

```
import emoji
print(emoji.emojize('Hola :earth_americas:'))
```

para producir la misma salida que en los dos ejemplos anteriores. No sé si merece la pena una biblioteca para esto, ya que de todas formas tienes que consultar el nombre del *alias* (`:earth_americas:`). Los tienes todos [aqui](https://www.webfx.com/tools/emoji-cheat-sheet/) pero al final casi resulta más simple copiar directamente el símbolo  de [este otro sitio](https://www.emojicopy.com) por ejemplo.

Comment: Nota: es muy facil meter emojis en windows, simplemente pulsando `win + .` (mantener pulsada la tecla de windows y le das al punto).